# Do we need to check Internal Consistency of Validated Questionnaire?

Tags: factor-analysis, survey

Do I need to necessarily conduct a reliability test to determine the internal consistency of the items in a questionnaire that I have adopted, even though that instrument had already been validated before when it was created? I have not made any change or revision to the validated instrument.
Kindly advise